# Get event on any tab click in ribbon in MS word VSTO add in

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

I have created a MsWordAddin using VSTO addin in visual studio for MS Office 2010.Till now I have added a new tab in Ribbon and customized task Pane.
What now I want is to get a event when user select any tab on Ribbon,so i can evaluate what user has performed on this event e.g. user select Page layout tab and change Page orientation from horizontal to landscape.

I found [SelectionChange,BeforeRightClick,BeforeDoubleClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document_events%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) document events,but they are not what i want.

Is there any way to get event in MS Word or any other workaround to evaluate such scenario ?

---

I want to evaluate as same way as [RibbonHero](http://www.ribbonhero.com/)
Hope this clears my question very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI), nor the Word object model, doesn't provide any event for that. If you have got your add-in's controls on a particular tab you may consider handling callbacks that should be fired when the tab is going to be shown.

> so i can evaluate what user has performed on this event e.g. user select Page layout tab and change Page orientation from horizontal to landscape.

Instead, I'd suggest handling the [Document's events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document_events%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks Eugene for response.But this is not how I want to evaluate.May be I am not clear in question,Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for response.But this is not how I want to evaluate.May be I am not clear in question,Sorry for that.I want to evaluate at the same time when user has clicked on Page layout and changed the layout.This is one step,like this there will be multiple skills to evaluate.If I take custom control like button in my addin,I can evaluate only when user click on that button and I dont want to give control to user for that.Anyways i have used very silly trick for evaluating...Time Tick event,I am evaluating on each tick whether user performed the skill or not.

Comment: I have edited the questions for making it more clear.Please have a look.

Comment: Finally, I have evaluated the skills on the click on custom button I have taken on Ribbon.And timer_tick is also an option in case you have to evaluate very few skills.

Answer (score -1):

Try using MSAA ..You can get sample code 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSOfficeRibbonAccessibility-cd7fe67f#content

I have implemented this and find very useful.