# VSTO Sample code For Sensitivity label Ribbon Item OnClick Events in C#

Tags: vsto, microsoft-information-protection

I need to get changes to a sensitivity label done by clicking the Ribbon item in Microsoft Word.

Does anyone have sample code on catching event changes for sensitivity labels in particular for VSTO C#?

We are using ribbon XML and not ribbon designer and extending AddInBase to start up the word application.

I have tried [Document events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431531/get-event-on-any-tab-click-in-ribbon-in-ms-word-vsto-add-in). I have tried [Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847915/override-word-paste-event-vsto).

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I can't find much documentation for VSTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some VBA references.

You can try using the [Document.SensitivityLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.sensitivitylabel) property on ThisDocument/ActiveDocument and listen to the [SensitivityLabel.LabelChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.sensitivitylabel.labelchanged) event

Comment: sorry I should have specified c#.

Comment: @lesleey86 - C# won't be any differ tent. Are you running into a particular problem translating that to C#?

Comment: @Dmitry The only active document property I have available to me comes from GetHostItem From the AddInBase Class in VSTO. This active document property does not have a SensitivityLabel property.

Comment: @lesleey86 - that means you have an out-of-date interop dll. Get the latest version, or generate one by adding Word to your project references (COM tab).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a mixture of @cs answer and @Dimitry's answer (I don't have enough reputation points to mark that your comment was very useful). So thank you very much both of you for your assistance

VSTO no longer has support, so visual studio office tools include interop dll v15.0.0 for .net framework version 4.7.2. On our development machine, we have office 365, which from what I read means the latest interop dll will be installed as part of the installation process which has Microsoft word object library v 16.0

[Adding Lastest interop to Visual Studio as a com reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvcdk.png)

However visual studio still did not update the interop interfaces. What I had to do was change the wrapper property in the csproject from

```
<WrapperTool>primary</WrapperTool> to <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
```

This updated the interfaces and allowed me to get access to the Document.SensitivityLabel object.

So thank you to all that commented it was greatly appreciated.